# showing elements in $\mathbb{Z}+\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\mathbb{Z}$ are associated

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, factoring, unique-factorization-domains

An exercise in my number theory class asks me find the integer solutions of $x^2+xy - y^2 = x + y$. The exercise was divided in parts:

1) I have shown that $R = \mathbb{Z} + \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\mathbb{Z}$ is a Euclidean domain. I did this with respect to the following function:
$$\varphi: R\setminus\{0\} \to \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}: a+b\phi \mapsto a^2 + ab - b^2$$
where $\phi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$.

2) I have shown that every unit in $R$ larger then $1$ is a power of $\phi$.

**actual question:**
3) In this part it is asked to show that if $p$ is a prime integer, then $p$ is either prime in $\mathbb{Z} + \phi\mathbb{Z}$ or it can be written as $(a + b\phi)(a + b - b\phi)$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. I think I was able to do this. However, it is also asked to show that these two elements are not associated unless $p = 5$. For $p = 5$, I have found that they are indeed associated, but I am having a hard time proving it is not for other primes. I know that they both have the same norm, but I am not sure how to proceed.

**EDIt:** as @Hurkyl suggested, I could consider the ratio of both:
$$\frac{a + b - b\phi}{a+b\phi} = \frac{(a+b - b\phi)^2}{a^2 + ab - b^2}$$
(by multiplying both numerator and denominator by $a+b - b\phi$). This gives me
$$\frac{(a+b)^2 - 2(a+b)b\phi +b^2\phi^2}{a^2+ab - b^2}$$
and using that $\phi^2 = \phi + 1$, I find
$$\frac{a^2 + 2ab + b^2 - 2ab\phi - 2b^2\phi +b^2\phi +b^2}{a^2+ab - b^2} = \frac{(a^2 + 2ab+2b^2) - (2ab + b^2)\phi}{a^2+ab - b^2}.$$
Since we consider $p = a^2 + ab - b^2$, we can rewrite this as 
$$\frac{(a^2 + 2ab + 2b^2) - (2ab + b^2)\phi}{p}$$
and here I am stuck...

Comment: Possibly stupid question: did you try simplifying their ratio? The same trick you use to do division in the complex numbers applies.

Comment: @Hurkyl: tried it, but I did not really find a useful reduction, currently checking my computations once more to see if I did not make any computational errors

Comment: I guess you need to use part 2 to get: $a + b \phi \sim a + b - b \phi \iff a + b \phi = \phi^n (a + b - b \phi)$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$.

Comment: @AlexVong: I know that all units are $\pm\phi^m$ for some integer $m$. I do not see how to use this...

Comment: @Student Maybe something like the following would work: Let $p = (a + b \phi)(a + b - b \phi)$ be a prime integer. Suppose $a + b \phi$ is an associate of $a + b - b \phi$. Then by part 2, we have $a + b \phi = \phi^n (a + b - b \phi)$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$. Now we want to show $p = 5$...

Comment: Correction: In the above equation, it should be $\pm \phi^n$ instead of $\phi^n$.

Comment: Hmmm, still can't solve this problem. Some progress is made though. Our goal is to solve the equation $a + b \phi = \pm \phi^n (a + b - b \phi)$. Using the fact that, [$\phi^n = F_{n - 1} + F_n \phi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Decomposition_of_powers_of_the_golden_ratio), one can show that $$\begin{pmatrix} F_{n - 1} + 1 & -F_{n - 2} \\ F_n & -F_{n - 1} + 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$...

Comment: ...or $$\begin{pmatrix} F_{n - 1} - 1 & -F_{n - 2} \\ F_n & -F_{n - 1} - 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ for $n \ge 2$. When $n$ is odd, the determinant is nonzero, so $a = b = 0$, implying $p = 0$ which is a contradiction. So we are left with the cases $n = 1$ and $n$ being even. The $n = 1$ case is easy but I don't know how to solve latter case.

Comment: @AlexVong: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. The goal of this exercise is to show that the integer solutions to $a^2+ab - b^2 = a+b$ are given by $a = (-1)^mF_{m+1}F_{m-1}$ and $b = (-1)^mF_{m+1}F_m$, so I am not sure if I could even use the fact you state (in order to avoid circle reasonings...)

Comment: @Student You're welcomed! It is fun to think of this kind of questions. For the circularity problem, I think they can be resolved. I remember when I studied elementary number theory last semester, those formulae follow from the theory of continued fractions. Many of those theorems only require induction. The proofs are tedious though.